# Frequently used snippets

Tags: windows, copy-paste

I am looking for an application that stores frequently used text snippets and lets me copy a snippet to the clipboard with a single click.

Bonus would be to allow pasting into the previous window via a button or double-click.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps Lintalist does what you want. You can store as many texts as you like and search for all snippets incl. additional options to add information to a snippet before it is pasted or stored in the clipboard. At the same time you can use hotkeys and shorthand for often used snippets.

Website: https://lintalist.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

I am definitely going to check out @Lintalist's answer.

There are a few basic apps that I deem to be indispensable and have spent a ***lot*** of time looking for the best in cataloger for each. At or near the top of the list is clipboard management.

I didn't just search once & freeze everything in place. I am open to change and a few times each year I look for better.

For years now, my clipboard manager has been [Ditto](https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/)

> lets me copy a snippet to the clipboard with a single click.  ☑
> Bonus would be to allow pasting into the previous window via a button or double-click.   ☑

From the website:

- Easy to use interface
- Search and paste previous copy entries
- Keep multiple computer's clipboards in sync
- Data is encrypted when sent over the network
- Accessed from tray icon or global hot key
- Select entry by double click, enter key or drag drop
- Paste into any window that excepts standard copy/paste entries
- Display thumbnail of copied images in list
- Full Unicode support(display foreign characters)
- UTF-8 support for language files(create language files in any language)

It handles images, text, MS Word & Excel, etc, etc.  Lets you decide how many entries to keep, how long for & more, plus, as you require, you can pin snippets which will never be deleted.

Give it a try & let us know what you think. I am off to try Lintalist now.